# how to determine when to use procedure and when to use function in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to determine when to use **procedure** and when to use **function** in oracle and which would be more efficient for a particular scenario.

Comment: It's not a matter of 'efficient', it's a matter of purpose.  A function should not modify any data. It should only return a single value, such that it could be used in a query.  Think about how oracle's built-in functions behave and are used (ie:  to_date, to_char, trunc, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The conditions are determined by the task. There are many criteria and it can't be listed them in one post. In the simplest cases, if you need to get some value by a set of arguments, then it can be a function. If you need to get a set of data, it can be either a cursor or a set of data returned by a procedure or function. It is important to note that this procedure cannot be used directly in the SQL core.

If you find it difficult to choose, then describe your task and goal, then it will be easier for us to help you decide on the selection criteria.